# How to build a caseinsensitive wildcard query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am currently trying to write a Elasticsearch query that will have to be case insensitive, with a wildcard at the end of it and it has to run on Tokens and not on the pure Texts. I tried to use the WildcardQuery but that one does not seem to query the Tokens. If anyone has a tip on where to look for more information besides the ElasticSearch Documentation i would really appreciate it.

My current query:

```
SearchSourceBuilder search = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource()
        .size(0)
        .query(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("myProperty", "*" + term + "*"))
        .aggregation(AggregationBuilders
            .terms("byBrand")
            .field("myProperty")
            .size(3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `query_string`. It's [allowing for a wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) to be used but, to be honest, putting a wildcard as first element (the SQL way of running a match) is the wrong way from ES point of view. I mean, it will work, but the performance might not be the best one. ES is a search engine, not a database, think about using analyzers to create tokens that can match your search string. For example, use [`ngrams` to split your text into tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html) and then use a `terms` query to search for your term without any wildcards.